# before plugin parameter magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, plugin, interceptor, before-plugin

I am writing a before plugin for below public method.

```
public function setup($user,$pass,$url = null){
 $this->username = $user;
        $this->password = $pass;
        if ($url) {
            $this->uri = $url;
        }
        return true;
}
```

I write like below

```
public function beforeSetup($subject, $user, $pass,$url = null){
     $user = "test";
     $pass = "hello";
     return array($user,$pass,$url);

    }
```

As per dev docs `If there is more than one argument, the method should return an array of those arguments.`
But am getting : Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

How we handle more than one argument in plugins??

Comment: Change it `return array($user,$pass,$url);` to `return [$user,$pass,$url];` and after that do di compile properly.

Comment: it doesn’t help, still the same error

Comment: your code seems is ok with me . Very strange it is not working

Comment: Just to an try    `return array($user,$pass,$url = null);` note that first delete all file  from  `generate/code` and `generate/metadata`  then do di compile

Comment: if I pass null then it gave me `Invalid arguments passed ` before applying plugin

Comment: Hi @Daniel_12, I have the issue, did you find a solution for  this?